# Why is the coproduct in $\mathsf{Grp}$ so different from the coproduct in $\mathsf{Ab}$?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

Why is the coproduct in $\mathsf{Grp}$ so different from the coproduct in $\mathsf{Ab}$? What about $\mathsf{Grp}$ makes for a seemingly far-more-complicated coproduct? If your answer revolves around "$\mathsf{Grp}$ is not an abelian category", please explain in detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One quick answer is that the study of abelian groups is the same as the study of $\mathbb Z$-modules, while the study of groups is not at all the study of modules over a principal ideal domain (or any other ring). The theory of modules over a principal ideal domain is very down-to-earth, with a very nice representation theory, rank theory, etc.. Thus, the study of abelian groups is quite simpler than that of all groups.

A more direct, and still algebraic, answer is the following. Quite a lot of the difference between the categories can be seen just by examining free objects. The free abelian group on a set $S$ of generators is isomorphic to the direct product of $\mathbb Z$, with one copy for each generator $s\in S$. This is a very simple description of free objects, and the free objects are not very complicated. Note that the fact that these are indeed the free objects in $Ab$ strongly relies on the commutative property. The relation $ab=ba$ for all generators immediately makes the resulting free object rather small, since many formal elements are identified at once. The situation is very different with groups. Free groups are much larger, and far more complicated already for two generators. As free objects govern, or hint at, many properties in a category, it follows that $Grp$ is much more complicated than $Ab$.

Lastly, an answer with a geometric flavour. Through the theory of fundamental groups and covering spaces, a strong relationship is made between groups and spaces. Not every space has an abelian fundamental group and thus the difference between $Ab$ and $Grp$ is somewhat quantified by the difference between studying just a small portion of spaces (those with abelian fundamental groups) and that of all spaces (remembering that for every group there exists a space with that group as fundamental group).

Comment: I am a bit confused by your focus on modules over a PID in the first part. The coproduct has the same nice description for modules over any ring, so the fact that groups are not modules over some ring is the main thing.

Comment: Yes @TobiasKildetoft, you are right. My intention was to direct OP to other differences between the two categories, not necessarily just coproducts. You are correct however that in the context of the question it is the PID part that should have been parenthetical, not the ring part. Thanks for your comment on this.

Comment: @IttayWeiss, thanks for the illuminating answer. In what sense do free objects teach us about the differences of structures of categories?

Comment: when all small coproducts and all coequalizers exists, then all small colimits exist. The proofs constructs the colimit as the coequalizers of a certain coproduct, so when the coproducts are very complicated, in a sense all colimits are very complicated.